# Request mapping in RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest

In my app (springboot 2.+) I have a RestController like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DeviceController {

   @GetMapping(value = "/devices") {
   public ResponseEntity<String> devices() {
    ...
   }
 }
}
```

Now, request with URI: */devices* - returns all devices

But request with URI: */devices?unknown_any_param=2* - also returns all devices

How can I make it so when I passing any unknown parameters, this method `devices()` is not calling, i.e. is returning the error '400 Bad request'?

I was try to point annottion like @GetMapping(value = "/devices", params={}) , but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all the parameters passed as below

```
public ResponseEntity<String> devices(
@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParameters)
```

Now check they keys if request parameter passes a valid list of parameters else

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: I also found this way, but I thought there might be some more. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should respond back with 404 'NOT FOUND' as there is no such device available with unknown_any_param=2.

**Still if you want to check-**

You can use Reflection API to check if key is valid or not. Consider-

```
public class DeviceDto{
    private String knownValue;
    @JsonProperty("unknown_any_param")
    private String unknownValue;
}
```

case 1: If param is same as the variable name.

```
DeviceDto.class.getDeclaredField("knownValue");
```

case 2: If param is same as the value in @JsonProperty and you know the variable name

```
DeviceDto.class.getDeclaredField("unknownValue")
     .getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class)
     .value();
```

case 2: If param is same as the value in @JsonProperty and you don't know the variable name

```
Arrays.asList(DeviceDto.class.getDeclaredFields()).stream()
     .filter(r -> "unknown_any_param"
                       .equals(r.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value()))
     .findFirst();
```